# Using AliasAnalysis interproceduraly in clang 3.3.1

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am working on a project extending clang 3.3.1 .

I would like to use the AliasAnalysis class and I am not sure, if I am missing something.
When I ask the AA, if memory locations in different functions alias, clang crashes with the following error: "BasicAliasAnalysis doesn't support interprocedural queries."
I guess, it might be a solution, to use a different kind of analysis, but I was not able to figure out how to do that in code. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any interprocedural AliasAnalysis in LLVM yet. Part of the problem is that we would need a new API to express the queries.

Consider a self-recursive function @f(noalias %x, noalias %y) which calls itself with @f(%y, %x). Today we answer that %x noalias %y, which is true within any single call frame. However, if you were to look across multiple call frames, you can see that %x in the callee may alias %y in the caller, therefore %x and %y in the same function may alias. That's the core reason why we would need to keep our current API separate from an interprocedural API.